# C- Putting Array Elements into Array in Function

Tags: arrays, function, pointers, menu, reference

I am completely new at writing code and am taking a C programming class.

I am attempting to write a program that is a bank menu. I am having trouble putting values into the array through the function. I think the last function with the pointer part is what I am having difficulty with. I appreciate answers, but I want to be able to understand what I did wrong and how I should recognize it.

Also any improvement you can think of besides that would be appreciated. Thanks!

*** Also, please note the entire code is not complete. I need to fix this one part to be able to write the others so this is where I am stuck.

```
 //
//  main.c
//  HMenuFunctionArray
//
//  Created by Yasmin on 5/13/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Yasmin Hosein. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define DEPOSIT 5

void choiceG(unsigned (*array[DEPOSIT]));

int main() {

char choice;
int sum, maxim, minim, aver = 0;
int count;
int array[DEPOSIT];


do {
printf("\nChoose an option from the menu below:\n");
printf( "\tG\t-\t" );
printf("Get a new deposit\n");
printf( "\tS\t-\t" );
printf("Sum of all deposits\n");
printf( "\tD\t-\t" );
printf("Deposits to be displayed from highest to lowest\n");
printf( "\tA\t-\t" );
printf("Average of all deposits\n");
printf( "\tL\t-\t" );
printf("Lowest deposit will be displayed\n");
printf( "\tQ\t-\t" );
printf("Quit the program\n");

printf("\nYour choice (please use uppercase): ");
scanf("%c", &choice);

switch (choice) {
    case 'G':
    choiceG (&array[DEPOSIT]);
        break;
    case 'S':
        printf( "G");
        break;
    case 'D':
        printf( "G");
        break;
    case 'A':
        printf( "G");
        break;
    case 'L':
        printf( "G");
        break;
    case 'Q':
        break;
    default:
        printf("Incorrect menu option selected.\n");
    }
   }
   while (choice != 'Q') ;
   }

void choiceG (unsigned *array[DEPOSIT]) {
int a[5] = { 0 };
int i, j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < DEPOSIT; ++i ){

printf("Deposit # %d - $",i);

scanf("%d",*a+i);}

printf("Your deposit amounts are: $ ");

for(j = 0; j < DEPOSIT ; j++)

printf("%p  ", (void *) &a[j]);

 return ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[DEPOSIT];
```

Creates an array of `int`. Ok.

```
choiceG(&array[DEPOSIT]);
```

Passes the address of the int at the `index = DEPOSIT`. However, that is an invalid index. Valid ones are `0 to DEPOSIT-1`. This should be:

```
choiceG(array);
```

That will pass the array - not just one element of it. Next,

```
void choiceG(unsigned (*array[DEPOSIT]));
```

I think you want to pass the array, so this should just be

```
void choiceG(int array[DEPOSIT]);
```

Lastly:

```
void choiceG(int array[DEPOSIT])
{
    int a[5] = { 0 };  // What is this for?
    int i, j = 0;

    // Get all the deposits from the user
    for(i = 0; i < DEPOSIT; ++i ){
        printf("Deposit # %d - $", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]); // Scan directly into the array
    }

    // Print all the deposits just entered
    printf("Your deposit amounts are: $ ");
    for (j = 0; j < DEPOSIT ; j++) {
        printf("%d  ", array[j]);  // Print the int value
    }
    printf("\n");   // Flush stdout

    return ;
}
```

Comment: That a[5] = { 0 } was initially in the for loop instead of the constant DEPOSIT. I had forgotten to remove it after I corrected myself. I had the notion that the way I had it was for the entire array not an index of the array. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There were several small issues with the code:

- Formatting matters as it improves readability.
- An array is nothing but    a pointer to the first element in the
  array, so passing the name of    the array is enough.

So when you define a function that takes in an array, just passing a pointer to the data type is enough. e.g. a function that takes in an array of integers can be declared as so:

```
void functionThatTakesAnArrayOfInts(int *array);
```

If you want to access an element in that array, you can just do:

```
array[index]
```

And if you want a pointer to that index in the array, you can just do:

```
&array[index]
```

The code below runs.

```
//
//  main.c
//  HMenuFunctionArray
//
//  Created by Yasmin on 5/13/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Yasmin Hosein. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define DEPOSIT 5

void choiceG(int *array);

int main() {
  char choice;
  int sum, maxim, minim, aver = 0;
  int count;
  int array[DEPOSIT];

  do {
    printf("\nChoose an option from the menu below:\n");
    printf( "\tG\t-\t" );
    printf("Get a new deposit\n");
    printf( "\tS\t-\t" );
    printf("Sum of all deposits\n");
    printf( "\tD\t-\t" );
    printf("Deposits to be displayed from highest to lowest\n");
    printf( "\tA\t-\t" );
    printf("Average of all deposits\n");
    printf( "\tL\t-\t" );
    printf("Lowest deposit will be displayed\n");
    printf( "\tQ\t-\t" );
    printf("Quit the program\n");
    printf("\nYour choice (please use uppercase): ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
      case 'G':
        choiceG (array);
        break;
      case 'S':
        printf( "G");
        break;
      case 'D':
        printf( "G");
        break;
      case 'A':
        printf( "G");
        break;
      case 'L':
        printf( "G");
        break;
      case 'Q':
        break;
      default:
        printf("Incorrect menu option selected.\n");
    }
  }
  while (choice != 'Q');
}

void choiceG (int *array) {
  int a[5] = { 0 };
  int i, j = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < DEPOSIT; ++i ) {
    printf("Deposit # %d - $",i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  printf("Your deposit amounts are: $ ");

  for(j = 0; j < DEPOSIT ; j++) {
    printf("%d  ", a[j]);
  }

 return ;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense, I got so frustrated that I had spent so long researching each topic (arrays/functions/pointers) individually and trying to figure out how they come together. You're explanation really helped, thank you! I think the part that had me confused was the fact that the way I wrote it only pointed to an index of the array not the whole array itself.